References appear as question marks using Springer template
I'm trying to use this template provided by Springer to write a paper and I'm having some trouble with the references.
I use the Texmaker editor with MiKTeX, and what I did for now was:

Open the sn-article.tex file using Texmaker

Change line 34 from \documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl} to \documentclass[iicol]{sn-jnl} to have the double column format (according to what is mentioned here under "Text Formatting Specifications", as well as on the 4th page of the user-manual.pdf file that is in the .zip of the template).

See that line 426 gives me an error, I comment it so the format is correct now (double column), but now the references appear as [?] and the Bibliography section disappears from the generated PDF.

Undo all changes but the references still don't work.


As you may understand, this left me a bit confused, as I changed a minimal thing and then did Ctrl+Z until I restored the file to its original state (this is, as I downloaded it), which did not fix the problem for some reason?
Then, I deleted the whole thing, re-downloaded the template, and opened it again. I tried changing the [sn-mathphys-num] to [iicol] again, which gave me an error, and then again I returned it to its original state (without doing the modification to line 426), after which I saw that, once again, the references broke down.
I'm really puzzled as I don't understand what the issue could possibly be. I tried looking for answers (I saw a post on a different forum which suggested pressing F6+F11+F6+F6, waiting between each step of course, which I did, and it did not work), but either I'm not good at searching or no one else had this problem before.
Hopefully I was able to communicate my issue clearly enough. If you have any advice on how I can solve this, I would be extremely grateful. :(

? are the expected output in initial runs of latex. You need to run bibtex https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number

Note that everything is manual in texmaker, here you need to press buttons to run pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex. You should do this each time you cite something new or change the bib file. I'm not sure how much of this is automated in the editor texstudio.

Why didn't you change \documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl} to \documentclass[sn-mathphys-num,iicol]{sn-jnl}? The options sn-mathphys-num and iicolaren't mutually exclusive. Of course, once the external .bbl file, which contains the formatted bibliographic entries, has been lost, it needs to be re-created by re-running BibTeX as well.
